Long exact sequence of intersected prime ideals
I'm considering a commutative local noetherian ring $R$ (in fact, $R$ is even Cohen-Macaulay) along with a number of prime ideals $I_i$. I can then construct the exact sequence
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow R/(\cap_{i} I_i)\rightarrow \bigoplus_i R/I_i\;.
\end{equation}
I want to somehow complete this to a long exact sequence, similar to the short exact sequence
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow R/(I_1\cap I_2) \rightarrow R/I_1\bigoplus R/I_2\rightarrow R/(I_1+I_2)\rightarrow 0\;.
\end{equation}
Is this possible, and if yes, how can I construct this sequence? The natural thing to do is to proceed along the lines of
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow R/(\cap_{i} I_i)\rightarrow \bigoplus_i R/I_i \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i<j} R/(I_i+I_j) \rightarrow \cdots
\end{equation}
but I'm having trouble showing this is exact.
